# CSS file not linking to a HTML file

Tags: html, css, django

I have this HTML file and I'm trying to link a CSS file to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Aqui podras veure el temps de vilafant en un futur, no tinguis presa</p>
    <h2>La humitat d'avui és: {{humitat}}</h2>
    <h2>La temperatura d'avui és: {{temperatura}} Cº</h2>
    <h2>La pressió d'avui és: {{pressio}}</h2>

    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" >
        <button>Update</button>
    </a>
```

When I execute this file, I get this error:

> Not Found: /weathersite/temps/templates/main.css

I don't understand why because they are in the same folder.

I have tried linking it normally with the link line of code.

Comment: I guess you are using django. if so then you need to create a separate folder for *css* files named `static` and then load that inside your html like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main.css' %}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, you may need to use something like:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}"/>
```

In this case, you must store main.css file in a folder called 'static' in your project directory.